# Proof for $\mathbf{M}$ unitary if $||\mathbf{M}\mathbf{v}|| = ||\mathbf{v}||$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Let $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{F}^{n, n}$. Then $||\mathbf{M}\mathbf{v}|| = ||\mathbf{v}||$($\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{F}^n$) implies that $\mathbf{M}$ is unitary.

My question is, how to prove this theorem? I know a proof under $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ using the identity $4\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} = ||\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v}||^2 - ||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}||^2$. However, this proof does not work when $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$ since the identity turns into $4\Re(\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}) = ||\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v}||^2 - ||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}||^2$.

Comment: You need $M$ to be a "surjective" transformation as well for this to be true.

Comment: **HINT** Use that $$\langle v,v \rangle =\|v\|^2=\|Mv\|^2=\langle Mv, Mv \rangle = \langle v, M^*M v\rangle $$ What does this tell you about the matrix $M^*M-I$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity):
$$\langle x,y\rangle=\frac{\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2+\mathrm{i}\|x+\mathrm{i}y\|^2-\mathrm{i}\|x-\mathrm{i}y\|^2}{4}\quad\forall x,y\in\mathscr H,$$ which is true for *any* pre-Hilbert space $(\mathscr H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ over $\mathbb C$, not just Euclidean ones. The proof is conceptually straightforward, though it involves a series of tedious manipulations.